# Cypress 5.1.0 - route2 - do the single origin rules for cy.get / cy.request also apply here? Or am I missing something?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use cy.route2 to intercept fetch network calls...

If I do something like :

`cy.route2('https://localhost:1234', {statusCode: 500})`

This works fine and requests including localhost:1234 get intercepted. But if I try to intercept a different request, on a different host:

`cy.route2('somehost.region.amazonaws.com/url_a/url_b', {statusCode: 500})`

Network requests to somehost.region.... don't get intercepted, and proceed to the remote URL as usual.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [defect](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8487) in Cypress that caused `route2` not to match external HTTPS domains. It was fixed in `5.3.0` [version](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#5-3-0).